# Различные элементы для разных устройств (ipad и iphone)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Изначально проект верстался под `w`Any `h`Any.

Возникла необходимость в дополнительном представлении для `iPad`, но `tableView` для этой верстки хочу поменять на `collectionView`, иначе интерфейс будет не красивым.

Подскажите, как правильно поступить в этом случае? Переключить size class на `w`Regular `h`Regular, удалить `tableView`, добавить `collectionView` и через логику в коде прописать управление через неё?
Или же ничего нельзя удалять - надо скрыть `tableView` в коде (если устройство iPad)?

Answer (score 1):

Лучше TableView заменить на CollectionView (в обоих ориентациях), достаточно делать ширину ячеек равной ширине CollectionView. При повороте анимировано подменять CollectionViewLayout (или какие-либо значения в нём). При этом будет красивая анимация.

Так же можно сделать отдельный ViewController, так как если вы наделаете в одном классе и методы TableViewDelegate и CollectionViewDelegate будет каша. И загружать этот ViewController для iPad.

Аналогично можно делать если вёрстка в различных ориентациях отличается (например, в Портретной одна таблица, а в Lanscape две независимых таблицы).

При этом если выделить получение данных в отдельный класс и другие операции бизнес логики в базовый класс, то классы, отвечающие за интерфейс будут не очень большими.

Если этот экран нужно показывать во многих местах, то чтобы не дублировать код загрузки, стоит сделать контроллер-контейнер, который будет загружать нужный дочерний контроллер и добавлять на себя в зависимости от устройства.